# AWS Cognito: how to develop an app offline?

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I an working on c# Lambda and need to debug my application in work with AWS Cognito.
Is there any offline Cognito emulators etc?
The LocalStack contains it but in the Pro version only. It is not a free.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a limited offline cognito in local with this :
https://github.com/jagregory/cognito-local

It doesn't support all features yet.

Comment: yes, its really great idea, I have tried but my c# code does not work or mat be I do not know what parameters to use. I have created the issue. Or may be I need the c# sample.